# cross rider extension to fetch new posts from feed using google feeds api

Tags: crossrider

I am trying to create an extension to display all the latest posts fetched from my feed using google feeds api. To implement this, I have added this code in background.js:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
// Global variable to hold the toggle state of the button
var buttonState = true;

// Sets the initial browser icon
appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('images/icon.png');
// Sets the tooltip for the button
appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('My Postreader Extension');   
appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({
    resourcePath:'html/popup.html',
    height: 300,
    width: 300
});});
```

and in **popup.html**,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">
function crossriderMain($) {eval(appAPI.resources.get('script.js'));   }</script>
</head>
<body><div id="feed"></div></body></html>
```

The **script.js** file is-

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.xxxxx.com/feed/");
  feed.setNumEntries(10);
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', entry.link);
        link.setAttribute('name', 'myanchor');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        div.appendChild(link);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

But I am unable to get desired result.The popup doesn't display anything.It just remain blank.

Comment: The background.js code and popup.html code look sound in general, but it seems from the script.js file that the "google" object is not defined? Are you loading it in another script? Is there meant to be another SCRIPT tag to the google feed API in the popup.html header? Also, do you see any error [messages in the console](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/howto_console_log)? [Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: not getting any error message in console

Comment: yes there should be another script tag to google feed api in popup.html. thanks, let me try

Comment: added `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` in the head of popup.html, but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a resource file for the popup's content, it's best to load the remote script from the **crossriderMain** function, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">
function crossriderMain($) {
  appAPI.db.async.get('style-css', function(rules) {
    $('<style type="text/css">').text(rules).appendTo('head');
  });

  appAPI.request.get({
    url: 'http://www.google.com/jsapi',
    onSuccess: function(code) {
      $.globalEval(code);
      appAPI.db.async.get('script-js', function(code) {
        // runs in the context of the extension
        $.globalEval(code.replace('CONTEXT','EXTN'));

        // Alternatively, run in context of page DOM
        $('<script type="text/javascript">').html(code.replace('CONTEXT','PAGE DOM')).appendTo('head');
      });
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div id="feed"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee]